# Separate downloader class (separate thread) accessed by different activities

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, download

**Intro** : I have 3 activities, `DashBoard`, `Feed` and `Events`. DashBoard is the launched when the application launches. From there the user can goto Feed or Events.

**Problem** : I want to initiate a download (in a separate thread, of course) when the `DashBoard` launches. From there the user can goto `Feed` or `Events`, and the download would be in progress or already finished. The activities `Feed` or `Event` (which ever appropriate at the instance) should be notified that the download is finished and the data is available. What is the best way to accomplish this?

**My current code** : I have a downloader class `DownloadHandler` which gets initiated by the `DashBoard` activity. This class downloads on a separate thread. The class keeps track of a boolean called `completed`. It is instantiated to `false` and when the download completes it is changed to `true`.

Currently My classes `Feed` or `Events` will poll the variable `completed` every 100ms or so in a separate thread so it doesn't block the UI thread. and when the `completed` variable becomes `true` it calls a function in that specific class which then queries the `DataHandler` class for the downloaded data.

---

This does work, but I feel like my logic is a bit messy and there must be a better way to do it. Because I am using two separate threads, one for downloading, one for polling the completed variable. Is there a better way to do this?

I have read on `AsyncTask` and different callbacks, but the problem is I cannot specify a callback in a specific class. Because when the download completes the current activity might be `DashBoard`, `Events` or `Feeds`. There is no guarantee which activity will be in front when the download finishes.

Comment: https://github.com/rajeshcp/Android-Download-Manager, See this basically this is a single ton class(DownloadManager) which will take care of all your http calls inside your application, you can have a look at this, this is the same thing i used in many of my applications  thanks

Comment: Im afraid a download Manager class is not what i require. I already have a working download manager class. I just need it to be able to call back on finish to a function depending on which activity is open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would fire up a broadcast in my download thread (seting up an intentfilter for that) and registerreceiver in Feeds and Events (dont forget to unregister them in onStop() ).
I use this solution often for this purpose - its easy and makes a good job.

```
BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
};
```

you should solve the rest on your own :) isnt that hard. There are many tuts for that or buy a standard book to get in android.

Comment: sounds like a good idea. Could you give me a bit of code example. Just an overview. How to register a broadcast reciever in the Events and Feeds specifically. Because all the examples I see on the internet uses a seperate BroadcastReciever class..

Comment: as it was accepted as answer yesterday... a smarter solution would be a abstract class extending activity and Feed and Events extending this abstract class. Setting up a Listener in the download thread and registering one in onStart of the abstract Activity (dont forget to unregister in onPause) would do a smart job.
But the Broadcast approach also does a good job and has the advantage that the activities dont have to know something about the lifecycle of the download thread.

Comment: Yes. I actually went with a sub-pub pattern with the activities and a singleton downloader class. Which is overall the same as what you've said.